# must be a control always assigned to a variable?

Tags: c#

I tried this construct in C#:

```
    private class DailyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public DailyTextBox(int x, int y)
        {
            ...
            this.Location = new Point(x, y);
            this.Size = new Size(50, 20);
            this.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
    groupBoxControl.Controls.Add(new DailyTextBox(100, 90));
```

The `TextBox` control created with `new` directly in the `.Add()` function is never assigned to a variable. The code is compiled without any error and the result on the screen looks OK. Because I am C# beginner I am not sure if there is a side effect I do not know.

Can I used it this way? I am accessing the variables in a general function which does not need the variables - only access to the controls which is also assured without variables.

Comment: A variable is nothing but a reference to an object. `groupBoxControl.Controls` is a list, which is nothing but a list of references to some objects as well, so it is the "variable" here. To sum things up, this is a perfectly valid way to instanciate objects.

Comment: You can do it that way. But you cannot refer to it easily. You get a reference to it by either using `groupBoxControl.Controls.Find(name, false).First()` or via `groupBoxControl.Controls.OfType<DailyTextBox>().First()`. Instead of `First` you can also enumerate them in a `foreach` if you have multiple.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The reference is in my case never a problem. Therefore I do not want to use any variables because I consider them - in my case - redundant.

Comment: @AlBundy: i would use a local variable anyway, in the case you want to subscribe an event, f.e. the `TextChanged` event.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Exactly: I have lot of identical objects and then I would have to subscribe each time the event. Now I do it only once in the class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your code is correct.

You can create and pass objects without ever assigning them to a local variable, instance field, or similar.

The most extreme case to demonstrate that is something like the following - assume this class:

```
public class Example
{
    public int ProvideNumber()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

You can then use this class, for example, as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Example().ProvideNumber().ToString());
```

As you see, this instantiates the class `Example`, but it does not assign the reference to the new instance to any variable or anything else; it just invokes a method, and the new instance will immediately be out of scope after that again.

This works for arbitrary classes, control classes are not an exception. The only important issue you should be aware of is that some classes need to be [disposed of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.idisposable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In that case, it makes sense to assign the reference to a variable simply because you probably want to do something with the new instance *and* then invoke [`Dispose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @"_.. and the new instance will immediately be out of scope after that again_": This is exactly I do not want to happen. My sample code avoids this? I need the instance to be "alive" after the `.Add()` function

Comment: @AlBundy: Yes, because in your sample code, you actually do assign the new control to something like a variable (a method argument), and within that method, the reference gets further assigned to something else like a variable (probably a field in an array). Therefore, in your sample code, your instance will stay alive.

Comment: To precise things, your instance will be alive as long as its container (`groupBoxControl.Controls`) is alive.